# Abstract Properties with a foreign key in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

**UPDATE**:
I updated the classes to look more like my actual model. When I remove the Assignable property from the Document base entity, everything works.

Is something like this possible to map in EF 4.1?

```
public abstract class Entity
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
}    

public abstract class Assignable:Entity
    {

    }

    public class Contact: Assignable
    {
         public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public class Partner: Assignable
    {
         public string Area {get;set;}
    }

    public abstract class Document: Entity        {

         public Guid AssignedToId {get;set}
         public Assignable AssignedTo {get;set;
    }

    public class Submittal: Document
    {
         public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
    }
```

Mapping:

```
    public class EntityConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity
        {
            protected EntityConfiguration()
            {
                HasKey(e => e.Id);
                Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            }
        }

    public class AssignableEntityMapping<TEntity>: EntityConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity: Assignable
{

}
    public class DocumentEntityMapping<TEntity>: EntityConfiguration<TEntity>
        {
            public DocumentEntityMapping()
            {

                HasOptional(e => e.AssignedTo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.AssignedToId);
            } 
        }

public class ContactMapping: AssignableEntityMapping<Contact>
{
....
}

public class PartnerMapping: AssignableEntityMapping<Partner>
{
....
}

public class SubmittalMapping: DocumentEntityMapping<Submittal>
{
....
}
```

If this is possible how do I setup the mapping so that the AssignedToId is a foreign key to one of the concrete entities?  I created a mapping for the Document entity and I get the error: "The property 'Id' is not a declared property on type..." I am guessing it is because EF doesn't know how to discriminate what the AssignedToId refers to?

Comment: You don't need a mapping at all, it just works with conventions. What is the mapping you have created?

Comment: @Slauma: I updated my question..I think I may need to have a Assignable table with FKs to any property that is ofType Assignable. Maybe?

Comment: The mapping code even doesn't compile, especially for `DocumentEntityMapping`. And `Document` has a duplicate `Id`. Are you using TPH or TPT inheritance? I was trying to reproduce your exception, but I wasn't able.

Comment: @Slauma: It probably doesn't compile for you, because I forgot to update the Document entity and the EntityConfiguration (had some extra props in the example that were not part of the example).

Comment: I believe that it must be: `DocumentEntityMapping : EntityConfiguration<Document>`. Is the class `Entity` part of your model, i.e. do you have a `DbSet<Entity>` or some navigation properties of type `Entity` in other classes? This would be a problem and explain the exception.

Comment: @Slauma: Entity is not a DbSet. Entity is the base class all entities derive from. I never use Entity as a navigation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of extra architecture around the `Contact` and `Partner` entities that I could not use something like a [TPH (Table Per Hierarchy)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) approach. EF doesn't know how to map the AssignedToId in the `Document` class since i was trying to use [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) at the same time. I ended up just adding all the "assignable" types to the Document class for now. If there is another way around this, I'd like to know.

```
public abstract class Document: Entity
{
     public Guid? AssignedContactId {get;set;}
     public Contact AssignedContact {get;set;}
     public Guid? AssignedPartnerId {get;set;}
     public Partner AssignedPartner {get;set;}
}
```